# dependent wife and husband is funding the whole trip. How do I fill in the 'Income and Expenditure' section in UK standard Visitor visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

My husband and I are Indian Citizens currently residing in the US and we are applying for UK standard Visitor visa. With the help of this forum, I now understand that if the primary is bearing the whole cost, he has to mention the total expenditure and we need not split the amount for dependents.  However, I'm not able to enter 'zero' in any of the fields in 'Income and Expenditure' section. Can anyone please clarify this issue?